# nodejs make image from smaller images?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

I have some small images that tiled together make a fullsize image. The tiles are saved on the server. I would like to stitch the tiles together in the right position and create 1 image file on disk made up of all the tile files. How can I do this in nodejs?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is probably to invoke a tool like ImageMagick, which has a [`montage`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php) command that does exactly what you're looking for.

This would be fairly straightforward to implement yourself, but I see that [this fork](https://github.com/enobrev/node-imagemagick) of node-imagemagick has `montage` support.

Comment: nice; I can't believe that's been around since November; node is sure screaming along on libs!

Comment: I see, that looks like good way. I am trying to use the forked version of image magick that has the montage feature but I am not sure how to get a forked version of npm module install. Any hints?

Comment: You should be able to add it as a dependency in your `package.json` with the GitHub tarball URL, e.g. `"dependencies" : { "imagemagick" : "https://github.com/enobrev/node-imagemagick/tarball/master" }`. See `npm help json` ([also here](http://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#dependencies)) for more information.

Comment: I tried to do what it's shown here but no luck yet.....http://debuggable.com/posts/how-to-fork-patch-npm-modules:4e2eb9f3-e584-44be-b1a9-3db7cbdd56cb   But I guess this is another question.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Since node.js doesn't have a graphics editing suite, your best path would be to</s>

You could call an external script, [using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922276/how-to-combine-multiple-pngs-into-one-big-png-file), [using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719909/joining-multiple-images-into-one-with-a-php-script), or the language you feel most comfortable hacking with.

There's plenty of material on [how to run a script from node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443597/node-js-execute-system-command-synchronously), so I won't mess around with that here.

However, I would suggest that you pass a temporary filename as an argument to the script, then when it finishes executing, go get that file rather than trying to read back the binary as a return value or something equally convoluted.